# make: *** No rule to make target `gcc', needed by `libmy.so'. Stop

Tags: c, makefile, shared-libraries

I would like to compile .c files to a .so (shared library).
And I don't understand why, I have that makefile that makes me an error:

```
LIB = libmy.so

SRC =   lib.c

CC = gcc

OBJ = $(CC) -c -fPIC $(SRC)

all: $(LIB)

re: fclean all

$(LIB): $(OBJ)
        $(CC) -shared -fPIC $(OBJ) -o $(LIB)

clean:
        $(RM) $(OBJ)

fclean: clean
        $(RM) $(LIB)
```

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Maybe instead of tabulators you have spaces?

Comment: Write LIB = -llibmy? I believe that should do the trick. The -l tells the linker to link the library by the name.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium That would resolve a linker error, but here it's `make` itself who chokes.

Comment: Shouldn't `OBJ = $(CC) -c -fPIC $(SRC)` be `OBJ = mylib.o`?

Comment: @user786653 It should, definitely. Post that as an answer.

Comment: @user786653 `OBJ = mylib.o`, that's exactly the same I'm doing. I believe. =x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in the following line:

```
$(LIB): $(OBJ)
```

When expanded this becomes:

```
libmy.so : gcc -c -fPIC lib.c
```

Hence the error.

What you probably wanted was :

```
OBJ = lib.o
```

To save you having to manually convert all `.c` source files to `.o` you can use a rule like this instead of `OBJ = lib.o`:

```
OBJ = $(SRC:%.c=%.o)
```

This creates a variable `OBJ` containing a list of all the files in `SRC` with any `.c` extension changed to `.o`.  eg.  If we had `SRC = foo.c bar.c` then the rule above would automatically expand to:

```
OBJ = foo.o bar.o
```

Comment: he also needs to add a rule to generate `$(OBJ)`

Comment: @Christoph Not necessarily. `make` has implicit rules for compiling C: it invokes `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<`.

Comment: @H2CO3: you're right - I missed that because I never rely on implicit rules

Comment: But that won't generate a .so file here.

Comment: @Elfayer: according to the manual, there are indeed no implicit rules for generating shared libs; the implicit rule generating object files is `$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c`, btw

Comment: With the code of Austin Phillips I always have the same error.

Comment: Did you *replace* `OBJ = $(CC) -c -fPIC $(SRC)` with `OBJ = lib.o`?

Comment: @Christoph No problem, neither do I, and in fact me too, I tend to spell out all rules, I just though it was worth mentioning.

Comment: @AustinPhillips Well don't know what I missed, but that's working ! =) The only thing is that I'll have to rewrite all .c I want to compile in .o . How can I do something like : `OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)` ? That doesn't work because I recompile then with -fPIC.

Comment: @Elfayer Answer updated.  As others have mentioned, it's generally a good idea to write your own rules rather than rely on the implicit rules so that you're sure the correct compile command will be used, include any flags you may require such as `-fPIC`.

Comment: I have that error while compiling with the Makefile : `lib.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against '.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(LIB): $(OBJ)
```

expands to

```
libmy.so: gcc -c -fPIC $(SRC)
```

ie you put your recipe into the depency list, and make rightfully complains.

Personally, I'd write the makefile like this:

```
CC := gcc
RM := rm -f

LIB := libmy.so
OBJ := lib.o
GARBAGE := $(OBJ)

.PHONY: all clean realclean

all: $(LIB)

$(LIB): LDFLAGS += -shared
$(LIB): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $<

$(OBJ): CFLAGS += -fPIC
$(OBJ): %.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

realclean: GARBAGE += $(LIB)
clean realclean:
    $(RM) $(GARBAGE)
```

Note that your original version did not contain a rule to make `$(OBJ)`. If you wanted to use the implicit one, you would need to add `-fPIC` to `CFLAGS`.

Answer (score 0):

That works :

```
LIB = libmy.so

SRC =   lib.c

CC = gcc

OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)

all: $(LIB)

re: fclean all

$(LIB):
        $(CC) -c -fPIC $(SRC)
        $(CC) -shared -fPIC $(SRC) -o $(NAME)
clean:
        $(RM) $(OBJ)

fclean: clean
        $(RM) $(LIB)
```

I just need `OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)` in `fclean`